# Setting the text direction for a Label in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, localization

I'm working on a multi-lingual application which requires me to change the text direction (either ltr or rtl) dynamically according to the user language.

I used a label for this. I assigned it a css class which would set the direction but its not working.

I also added a style to its CssStyleCollection list but its not working too.

Where am I doing it wrong? What are the ways in which it can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you post the CSS you're using, I may be able to identify anything that could be wrong with it. Otherwise, try this in your label control:

```
Label myLabel = new Label();
myLabel.Attributes.Add("dir", "rtl");
```

Of course, you may want to set the direction at a top-level tag such as the `<body />` so it affects the entire page and not just one label.

Answer (score 4):

There is a great [resources on MSDN that should be helpful](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twe16yc2.aspx).